# Bind text to property of child object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Using knockout.js, is it possible to bind to a property of a child object of a JSON object from the server?  Specifically, if I'm given an object from the server that looks like this:

```
var obj = {
    list: [ { key: "a", value: 1 },
            { key: "b", value: 2 },
            { key: "c", value: 3 }        
        ],
    selected: {
        key: "",
        value: null  
    }
};
```

I create a viewModel from this javascript object via the "mapping" plugin:

```
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(obj);
```

And I bind `list` to a `<select>` tag like so:

```html
<select data-bind="options: list, optionsText: 'key', 
                   optionsValue: 'value', 
                   value: selected">
</select>
```

I've assigned the value to be the `selected` property of my viewModel.  This means, upon selecting an option, I can successfully query `viewModel.selected.key()` and `viewModel.selected.value()` in code and get the up-to-date values.

However, I am unable to bind the selected item's `key` or `value` data to be displayed on a span.  For instance, this doesn't display my selected value:

```html
<span data-bind="text: selected.value"></span>
```

Can I do what I want?  Do I need to resort to using a real simple template to establish proper context (ie: `selected`)?

I have an example of the situation [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Dubu9/1/).  I've even tried specifically mapping the child `selected` object to be an observable itself, but with no luck (see commented out mapping call with the additional options).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were on the right track with the mapping options.  You would want `selected` to be an observable, so your UI updates when you make changes in the dropdown.  In your case, it could even be empty.

One thing to note is that when the mapping plugin deals with an object like:

```
selected: { key="", value=null }
```

It will make `key` and `value` observables, but not `selected`.

One other issue that you are having is that your first select specifies `optionsValue: 'value'`.  This will cause it to write the `value` property of your object to `selected` instead of the object.

If you want to write the object itself, then you would want to completely remove the `optionsValue` binding.

Here is your fiddle with these updates:
http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Dubu9/2/

Comment: Fantastic, just what I was looking for -- and I suspected it was going to come from you.  =)  It's good to know I was on the right track with making `selected` itself observable as well.  I think establishing the `optionsValue` parameter -- by accident -- was the crux of the situation.  Thanks again!